# Migrating from web pack v1.15 config to v2.6.1

Tags: reactjs, webpack

Updated webpack to the latest version(2.6.1), so the webpack config file, that came with the boilerplate, became outdated...

Looked at the official documentation on [migration](https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/), but still a bit lost regarding how exactly i need to update my config file:

```
'use strict';

const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV;
const SaveAssetsJson = require('assets-webpack-plugin');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  devtool: '#source-map',

  // Capture timing information for each module
  profile: false,

  // Switch loaders to debug mode
  debug: false,

  // Report the first error as a hard error instead of tolerating it
  bail: true,

  entry: [
    'babel-polyfill',
    './assets/main.jsx',
  ],

  output: {
    path: 'public/dist/',
    pathInfo: true,
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filename: 'bundle.[hash].min.js',
  },

  resolve: {
    root: path.join(__dirname, ''),
    modulesDirectories: [
      'web_modules',
      'node_modules',
      'assets',
      'assets/components',
    ],
    extensions: ['', '.webpack.js', '.web.js', '.js', '.jsx'],
  },

  resolveLoader: {

  },

  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(['public/dist'], {
      verbose: true,
      dry: false,
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      minimize: true,
      output: {
        comments: false,
      },
      compress: {
        warnings: false,
        screw_ie8: true,
      },
    }),
    new SaveAssetsJson({
      path: process.cwd(),
      filename: 'assets.json',
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production'),
      },
    }),
  ],
  query: {presets: ['es2015', 'react'] },
  module: {

    rules: [
      {
        use: [
          "style-loader",
          "css-loader",
          "autoprefixer-loader",
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/, // sass files
        loader: 'style!css!autoprefixer?browsers=last 2 version!sass?outputStyle=expanded',
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|woff)(\?[a-z0-9]+)?$/, // fonts files
        loader: 'file-loader?name=[path][name].[ext]',
      },
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/, // react files
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loaders: ['babel?presets[]=es2015,presets[]=stage-0,presets[]=react'],
        include: path.join(__dirname, 'assets'),
      },

    ],

    noParse: /\.min\.js/,
  }

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end there were few deletion of the deprecated plugin calls and restructuring some of the fields. Here is the 2.6.1 compatible version, the parts of the file that were changed:

```
    'use strict';


module.exports = {
  devtool: '#source-map',

  // Capture timing information for each module
  profile: false,

  // Switch loaders to debug mode
  //debug: false,

  // Report the first error as a hard error instead of tolerating it
  bail: true,

  entry: [
    'babel-polyfill',
    './assets/main.jsx',
  ],

  output: {
    path: '/public/dist/', //This has to be an absolute path
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filename: 'bundle.[hash].min.js',
  },

  resolve: {
  //merging root and modules
    modules: [
      path.join(__dirname, ''),
      'web_modules',
      'node_modules',
      'assets',
      'assets/components',
    ],
    extensions: [ '.webpack.js', '.web.js', '.js', '.jsx'], //Removed empty entry
  },

  resolveLoader: {

  },

  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(['public/dist'], {
      verbose: true,
      dry: false,
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      minimize: true,
      sourceMap: true, //added this
      output: {
        comments: false,
      },
      compress: {
        warnings: false,
        screw_ie8: true,
      },
    }),
    new SaveAssetsJson({
      path: process.cwd(),
      filename: 'assets.json',
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production'),
      },
    }),
  ],
  module: {
//Modules are slightly differently listed now
    rules: [
      {
            test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
            use: [{
                loader: "style-loader" // creates style nodes from JS strings
            }, {
                loader: "css-loader" // translates CSS into CommonJS
            }, {
                loader: "sass-loader" // compiles Sass to CSS
            }]
      },
      {
      test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
      exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
      use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: ['es2015', "stage-0", 'react']
        }
      }
    }

    ],

    noParse: /\.min\.js/,
  }

};
```